# .net core rest api post end - read query string from body

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, http-post, asp.net-core-2.0

In .net core 2.1,

On HTTP **post** endpoint,

Is it possible to read query string parameter from body?

sample request body:

name="zakie"&country="uswest"&state="california"

Comment: A query string doesn't sit in the body of a request. You should specify the query string in the route.

Comment: It may also be useful if you provide a code snippet of what you are trying to achieve and what's going wrong for you :-)

Comment: Hi @Zackie Khan, why do you want to post body with query string format? Why not post with json format like:`{"name":"zakie","country":"uswest","state":"california"}`? Please share your detailed scenario and a code snippet.

Comment: @Rena, "why do you want to post body with query string format not json?" that is business requirement

Comment: Hi @ZackieKhan, any update?

Comment: @Rena, just controller action  "public void Test([FromForm] IFormCollection  model)"   does the trick, no custom code required. But you put in awesome effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could custom TextInputFormatter like below:

```
public class CustomInputFormatter : TextInputFormatter
{
    public CustomInputFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.UTF8);
        SupportedEncodings.Add(Encoding.Unicode);
    }
    protected override bool CanReadType(Type type)
    {
        return type == typeof(TestModel);
    }
    public override async Task<InputFormatterResult> ReadRequestBodyAsync(
        InputFormatterContext context, Encoding effectiveEncoding)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body, effectiveEncoding);
        var line = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var split = line.Split("&".ToCharArray());
        var model = new TestModel();
        foreach (var item in split)
        {
            var list = item.Split("=");
            var value = list[1].Replace("\"", "");
            model.GetType()
                .GetProperty(list[0], BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .SetValue(model, value, null);
        }
        return await InputFormatterResult.SuccessAsync(model);
    }     
}
```

Test Model:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public void Test([FromBody]TestModel model)
{
    //do your stuff..
}
```

Register the service:

```
services.AddMvc(options=> {
    options.InputFormatters.Insert(0, new CustomInputFormatter());
}).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
```

Result:

[image]